# Create filter for dynamically inserted image text

Tags: c#, image, winforms, text

I want to create filter insert text in my simple image editor program
based on this [nice article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7462/Dynamically-Write-Text-On-An-Image). I found out how to do it, but I need some configure.

1. I make insert text more dynamic, just like Photoshop or Notepad. User click add text icon, cursor change and when user click on canvas that will be position for text. I already found this solution by mouse down event to get x & y screen coordinate.
2. I wanna make after (1), program will create something like textbox (minus background & border) so user can type text on it where in tutorial text is static.

I don't have idea how to do this, can anyone give me suggestion or example maybe?

---

**Update**

i really don't have any idea how to make this question more clear, spesific, or etc
i already try to divided what i want to 2 problem and solved one of them
i know if there is not just single method to archive what i want...but i don't know if    there will be **triple many** (many many many) way to do it, so i must write spesific method i wanna use...
how can i know which one i will use if i even don't have any idea one of them....
in my mind just come dumb way create custom textbox with no background & border

---

**Code**

```
//set flagText active or not
private void InsertText(){
   if (flagText){
      flagText = false;
      imageBoxCamera.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
   }
   else {
      flagText = true;
      imageBoxCamera.Cursor = Cursors.IBeam;
   }
}

//in mouse down event i wanna create something like textbox (minus label & border) with coordinat x & y from mouse down
private void imageBoxCamera_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   if (flagText) {
        MessageBox.Show(Cursor.Position.X.ToString() + " " + Cursor.Position.Y.ToString());
   }
}
```

Comment: Show some code please. We need to see some effort on your part. Also, there would be many ways to do something like this - showing us your attempt can help steer answers in the right direction using what you currently have, instead of just being huge code dumps that you will struggle to implement.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead i'm sorry...i think i alwady describe my effort in first question...not by code but by sentence... i think it's will be more easy to understand than i give my snipped code....
and speak about code as i say in my question, i found nice article about it, and you can guess my code will be almost similiar to it (beside position text(1) of course)
so i don't bother post code again
hope this not break stack overflow ruler

Comment: The problem with your question is that it isn't specific enough. Questions here must ask about specific programming problems. Your question is too broad. You're asking "how do I implement this big feature called XYZ?". That is much too broad and would require an article-sized answer.. which SO isn't designed for.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead i'm sory again...i can clearly undestand what you mean... i think my question already specifix enough...i want to create something similiar textbox to type text in image... butnot textbox...if textbox can do it i just create it in mouse down event...but textbox background & border will destroy my image...is that clear to you?

Comment: If anyone would be kind enough to show me how to develop software to run a nuclear power plant's thermal core - please tell me. I have no idea how to do this, if anyone can give me examples or a suggestion maybe?

Comment: @SemiDemented is that sarcasm for my question? if yes...i'm sory i really don't know how to make it more spesific, as i say in my question i don't have any idea what control like textbox i must used to archive what i want...if you kindly give me suggestion what control i can use or how to make my question more clear, i will really apreciate & improve my question so other can understand

Comment: @Neversaysblack add code, man. Show the community you tried, or researched, or attempted to some degree. Don't just ask for an answer.

Comment: @SemiDemented you didn't read my comment for simon

Comment: @Neversaysblack I understand that, but StackOverflow isn't for tutorials, its for answering specific questions. You can't expect a person to answer a question as broad as yours.

Comment: @SemiDemented ok i understand.. i will add code :D

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on OpenPDN source code(fork for Paint.NET). 
As I know there is a similar function there
https://code.google.com/p/openpdn/source/browse/#hg%2Fsrc